# What is the '.' directory in Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, explorer

For example, a directory has the following files: (as shown in explorer)

```
index.php
hello.php
img
```

If you query it using windows or just type dir in cmd prompt it will have the following files:

```
.
..
index.php
hello.php
img
```

I understand that '..' is a link to the previous directory, but what exactly is '.' and how can it be used?  I've searched all over the internet, but no avail found for the single dot

Comment: It is the current directory

Comment: Oh I see.  So if someone read %path%\. it would display all the files in the current directory?

Comment: I did not tried it on windows but it seams to be like on Linux system (only for that purpose ;) ). When you want to go inside a directory, you can use ./tmp for example that means begin from here and go inside directory tmp which is a subdirectory of the current one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` can be used in some commands:  This will copy the files from c:\temp to the current directory:

```
copy c:\temp\*.* .
```

The `..` can be used to move to a higher directory.
This will change to the parent folder:

```
cd ..
```

Comment: `.` refers to the folder itself and can be used in all paths. Useless, but working example: `pushd "C:\.\Temp\..\Temp\.\subfolder\."`.

Answer (score 1):

The '.' indicates the current directory as per [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29). As you mentioned, '..' is a link to the previous directory. Ultimately the Operating System will choose how to indicate these, but it is pretty standard across all major OSs

Answer (score 0):

`.` is the same as the current directory, but in a relative way.

For instance if the current directory is `c:\temp` and if you cd in this directory, then `. == c:\temp`.

Answer (score 0):

In short . is the current directory and .. is the parent directory. It is convenient for you to write scripts with these keyword otherwise you have to write a long command.